# Unexpected behavior in the "scrap" module of Pygame when attempting to copy/paste Unicode text

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm currently working on a GUI toolkit in Pygame, and so far it's looking pretty good. I'm currently working on a text-box widget, and it is nearly done. But I would like to implement copy/paste support. I scrolled through the Pygame docs and found there is a module, `pygame.scrap`, which is for this purpose. When I first implemented it, I used the `pygame.SCRAP_TEXT` content type when making calls to the `scrap.get` and `scrap.put` methods. It worked like expected, but obviously copy/pasting Unicode text didn't work, since `pygame.SCRAP_TEXT` can only handle ASCII text. So I switched to using `"text/plain;charset=utf-8"` as the MIME type to pass to the scrap methods, and that's when everything stopped working correctly.

This is the code I'm currently using to get the clipboard content, with an OS check to make sure that the Unicode MIME type is only used if the host OS is Windows or Linux:

```
def paste_text(self) -> None:
    if sys.platform in ("win32", "linux"):
        data_type = "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        decode_format = "utf-8"
    else:
        data_type = pygame.SCRAP_TEXT
        decode_format = "ascii"
    try:
        text = pygame.scrap.get(data_type)
    except pygame.error:
        return None
    if text is None:
        return None
    print("Hex bytes:", "".join(char + ("" if index % 2 or index == len(text.hex()) else " ") for index, char in enumerate(text.hex(), start=1)))
    print("Glyph Representation: \"{}\"".format(text.decode("utf-8", "ignore")))
```

The one-liner print statement on line 14 is for debugging purposes, and it converts the `bytes` object into a string of hexadecimal numbers seperated by spaces, and prints this information to the terminal.

Now, I've checked the code above many times to figure out where I'm making a mistake, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. There are all sorts of weird behavior when using the code above to get the clipboard content... After some testing, I've found the following two big issues:

1. When an string containing only ASCII characters is copied to the clipboard from an external program, and then pasted into the Pygame application (which calls the method in the snippet above), the codepoint for a NULL character is added after each hex byte, plus two extra NULL characters at the end of the string. For example, the string `Hello, world!` should have the 13 hex bytes: `48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21`. But the hex bytes actually printed by the method above is the following: `48 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00 2c 00 20 00 77 00 6f 00 72 00 6c 00 64 00 21 00 00 00`.

If this was the only problem, it wouldn't be that hard to fix. I could simply filter out the NULL characters using the Python `str.isprintable()` method. But it's *not* the only problem. It bugs out even worse if the string contains Unicode characters:

2. When a string containing Unicode characters is copied from an external program and pasted into the Pygame application, the hex bytes that make up the string are replaced by a completely different byte sequence, with even the *length* of the byte sequence being different. Also, each Unicode string always gets corrupted into the same "different" byte sequence. It's like some kind of weird seeding algorithm. For example, if the Mandarin string `您好，世界！`, which should have the 18 hex bytes `e6 82 a8 e5 a5 bd ef bc 8c e4 b8 96 e7 95 8c ef bc 81` when encoded with UTF-8, is typed into an external text editor, then copy-pasted into the Pygame application, the hex bytes become: `a8 60 7d 59 0c ff 16 4e 4c 75 01 ff 00 00`, which is 4 bytes shorter... And when decoded with UTF-8, it becomes the string `` `}YNLu ``  ...

And it's not just pasting, copying text *from* the Pygame application is also very buggy. The below is the method I'm calling to copy the text currently selected in the text-box widget to the clipboard:

```
def copy_text(self) -> None:
    ...
        selection = self.text[self.select_start:self.select_end]
    if sys.platform in ("win32", "linux"):
        data_type = "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        text_bytes = selection.encode("utf-8", "ignore")
    else:
        data_type = pygame.SCRAP_TEXT
        text_bytes = selection.encode("ascii", "ignore")
    try:
        pygame.scrap.put(data_type, text_bytes)
    except pygame.error:
        return None
```

And as for the buggy behavior when copying:

1. When *any* text, whether pure ASCII or Unicode, is copied from the Pygame application, it **works correctly** *without* messing up the bytes if pasted *back* into the Pygame application. *But*, if the text is pasted into an *external* text editor, the byte sequence is replaced with one of a different length, with the same weird "seeding algorithm" effect mentioned above, since the same string will always produce the same corrupted text. For example, if the string `Hello, world!` is typed into the Pygame application and copied to the clipboard, then pasted into an *external* text editor, the string becomes the characters `效汬Ɐ眠牯摬`, with the 18 hex bytes `e6 95 88 e6 b1 ac e2 b1 af e7 9c a0 e7 89 af e6 91 ac`. That's 5 bytes longer than the original string, where did the extra 5 bytes even come from? And if the string `您好，世界！` is typed into the Pygame application (via pygame.TEXTINPUT events) and copied, then pasted into an external text editor, the characters become the following: `苦붥볯隸闧¼`, with the 26 hex bytes `e8 8b a6 ee 96 a8 eb b6 a5 eb b3 af ee 92 8c e9 9a b8 e9 97 a7 ee be 8c c2 bc`. That's 8 bytes longer than the original string.

What is causing all these weird issues? Am I making some huge mistake in my code without seeing it?

---

Update: As there doesn't seem to be a solution, I'm switching to using the `pyperclip` module instead of `pygame.scrap` for clipboard operations.

Comment: 0xA8 in isolation is not even valid UTF-8, ditto for 0xFF. The parts which can be decoded are pure ASCII and the rest is undefined.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'Hello, world'.encode( 'utf-8' ).decode( 'utf-16-le' )` returns `'效汬Ɐ眠牯摬'`. You see [Glyph 0: the `.notdef` glyph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph) for each _private use character_ in another example: `'您好，世界！'.encode( 'utf-8' ).decode( 'utf-16-le' )` ---> `'苦\ue5a8붥볯\ue48c隸闧\uef8c膼'` (i.e. `苦붥볯隸闧膼` if you `print()` the latter string)…

Comment: @JosefZ But I'm encoding the string into bytes using UTF-8 before placing the bytes into the clipboard, so shouldn't the bytes obtained from the clipboard be decoded using UTF-8 as well? Or does `pygame.scrap` automatically change the encoding of the bytes when getting/placing from/to the clipboard? I just double-checked the Pygame docs on the `scrap.get()` and `scrap.put()` methods, and it doesn't seem to say anything about them automatically changing the encoding... Also, if I'm making a mistake with encoding, why does it work correctly when text is copy/pasted within the Pygame application?

Comment: What's confusing me the most right now is how the bytes that make up the string are somehow not messed up if the copy/paste is within the Pygame application. For example, if I type `您好，世界！` into the Pygame app, and copy-paste it, it somehow works correctly. And from checking the debug output, I can see that the bytes which make up the string is also exactly the same. Why do the bytes only get messed up if the paste is between the Pygame application and an external application?

Comment: Which version of Python (`sys.version`)? What is your `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`?

Comment: @JosefZ I'm using Python 3.9.7 64-bit, and my Pygame version is `2.1.2`. `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` returns `'cp950'`. And my OS is Windows 10 Home version 22H2, if that helps.

Comment: What if you (temporarily) set [_Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support_](https://superuser.com/a/1435645/376602). Sorry, I don't use `pygame`. Could you switch to [`pyperclip` module](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) for clipboard operations? Another attempt: `set "PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8"` in system environment variables?

Comment: @JosefZ Yeah, I'm starting to think it's something wrong with the `pygame.scrap` module too, since I can't see what I'm doing wrong in my code. I'll take your suggestion and switch to using `pyperclip` for accessing the clipboard. Thanks for your help :)